# Kendo mvc Grid ClientTemplate javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo mvc Grid and using client template as a column and i wrote a javascript function in the template to return the script block but its seems not working and no javascript error. I also tried to write the script to the client template directly but its not working too.

//html in client template

```
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

     columns.Template(e =>
     { }).ClientTemplate(

         "<div class='table-responsive'>" +
              "<table border='0' class='table' >" +

                 ...................................                

              "</table>" +
         "</div>"+
          "#=AlignDiv(Id)#"
                         );
      })
```

//javascript function to return a script block as a string

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function AlignDiv(Id) {
      var result = "<script> $('.calDiv"+Id+"').map(function () {" +
           "return $(this).Height();" +
       "}).get()," +
       "maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);" +
       "$('.calDiv" + Id + "').height(maxHeight);" +
        "alert('test')<\/script>";
      return result;
  }
```

Thanks a lot,
Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to format Kendo Grid Column value with conditionally chosen action you can use one of the suitable examples below. For more information: [How Do I Have Conditional Logic in a Column Client Template?](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-have-conditional-logic-in-a-column-client-template)

***UI for Javascript:***

```
{
    field: "EmployeeName", type: "string", width: "55px", title: "Employee Name", 
            template: "#= GetEditTemplate(data) #"
}
```

***UI for MVC:***

```
...
columns.Bound(t => t.EmployeeName)
.Title("Status Name")
.Template(@<text></text>)
.ClientTemplate("#= GetEditTemplate(data)#").Width("55px");
...
```

***Javascript Method:***

```
<script>
//Change the color of the cell value according to the given condition
function GetEditTemplate(data) {
    var html;

    if (data.StatusID == 1) {
        html = kendo.format(
        //"<a class=\"k-button\" href='" + '@Url.Action("Edit1", "Controller")' + "/{0}" + " '>Edit</a>  ",
        "<span class='text-success'>" +
        data.EmployeeName
        + "</span>"
        );
    }
    else {
        html = kendo.format(
        //"<a class=\"k-button\" href='" + '@Url.Action("Edit2", "Controller")' + "/{0}" + " '>Edit</a>  ",
        "<span class='text-danger'>Cancel</span>"
        );
    }
    return html;
}
</script>
```